# C# mouse position returning bad screen coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates, resolution

Recently I've been trying to get my screen coordinates(using dual monitor) based on mouse position. I've tried :

1. System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
2. Mouse.GetPosition()
3. Control.PointToScreen

All the methods return bad coordinates in my application, for example, when it should be 1262 X it shows 1576 X etc. (All cordinates are 1.25 bigger than the real ones).

I've tried the application on other computers and it works fine, tried same resolution as other computers, changed icon scaling as well, but no luck.

What can be wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev make an answer with it.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski well, usually if question poster wants to accept some comment as answer - he asks about it. So if Rimvydas wants it - I can make an answer, otherwise it is not worth it.

Comment: Yes make it as asnwer